# How to invoke aws lambda with payload from Slack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, slack, slack-api

I attempt invoking lambda through the aws chatbot for Slack like so:

```
@aws lambda invoke --function-name lambda-identifier --payload {"key":"val"}
```

but it fails with:

```
!Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character ('“' (code 8220 / 0x201c)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
at [Source: (byte[])"{“key”:“val”}"; line: 1, column: 5] (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestContentException; Request ID: 13724903-b15f-48e6-bc1a-9c6f9386baf4; Proxy: null)
```

I suppose this happens because Slack converts the simple quotes `"` to the elegant ones: `“`. But I don't know how can I prevent this behavior.

Comment: Try  --payload '{"key":"val"}'

Comment: @RodrigoM even those are being autocorrected as I type: `‘{“key”:“val”}’`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to disable this damn thing:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was going insane.