# Pass event data to AWS Lambda through AWS CLI/Slack(ChatOps)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a very simple nodejs based AWS Lambda function which has an event variable that I am trying to pass through slack/AWS Cli while invoking the function on Mac OS. Below is the code

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
const a = event["domain"];
    return a;
};
```

On testing function in AWS Lambda console if I provide set it up in below way it works fine.

[image]

It works fine and shows the result as expected. But when I am trying to run it using AWS Cli or Slack(ChatOps) it is not passing the event data. Below is the lambda invokation command I am using,

```
@aws lambda invoke --invocation-type RequestResponse --function-name manrill-test 
--region us-east-1 --payload "{ \"domain\": \"xyz.com\" }"
```

This shows the below message and looks like the payload/ event data is not being passed properly.

```
ExecutedVersion: $LATEST
StatusCode: 200
Payload:
null
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Ideally it should show the value of event data which I am passing (xyz.com).

Comment: depending on the shell (windows cmd, powershell, bash, ...) you are using this `--payload "{ \"domain\": \"xyz.com\" }"` may not be interpreted correctly. Can you try passing you payload as a jsonfile `--payload file://payload.json` like described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html#API_Invoke_RequestSyntax

Comment: @derpirscher I am using MacOS. Sorry I just updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [AWS CLI V2](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html) then you need to add the "--cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out" flag to pass raw json

```
aws lambda invoke --invocation-type RequestResponse --function-name manrill-test --region us-east-1 --payload "{ \"domain\": \"xyz.com\" }" --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out response.json
```

Comment: This works fine on AWS Cli. Any idea what will work on slack channel using chatops?

Comment: As it runs the CLI commands for you, it should work too. What response do you get when adding the flag?

Comment: tried a few variation of you above mentioned command but looks like it doesnt work.

#this shows the default error/message which is I'm not sure which AWS service or operation you meant by "lambda invoke...

@aws lambda invoke --invocation-type RequestResponse --function-name manrill-test --region us-east-1 --payload "{ \"domain\": \"xyz.com\" }" --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out response.json

Comment: The only one without cli-binary flag and response.json file shows as the status code 200 but payload as null

Comment: Lolzz found out. the issue is not on slack or lambda, its mac os keyboard setting. you have to uncheck "use smart quotation and dashes" keyboard settings under Text tab

Answer (score 0):

the issue is not on slack or lambda, its mac os keyboard setting. you have to uncheck "use smart quotation and dashes" keyboard settings under Text tab. check out the answer on the below link.

[How to invoke aws lambda with payload from Slack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62741112/how-to-invoke-aws-lambda-with-payload-from-slack)